# How to specify individual username & password parameters with mongoskin?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

I'm connecting to a mongodb db with authentication with [mongoskin](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin), and know you can specify a db user like this:

`[*://][username:password@]host[:port][/database][?auto_reconnect[=true|false]]`

However im getting some malformed url errors (presumably from passwords), and I'd like to know if it's possible to pass the username/password parameters separately  from the url.  I'm using this kind of connection format:

`var db = mongo.db(DBURL, { safe: true, auto_reconnect: true });`

**Can the user/pass be specified in the options?**  I can't see from the documentation.

Comment: Have you tried encoding your password before adding it to the URL string? `encodeURIComponent(password)`

Comment: Ah no, good point I'll try that too.

Comment: That appears to be working - thanks! Still would be interesting to know if it's possible to specify alternatively.

Answer (score 2):

Looking [at the code](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin/blob/master/lib/mongoskin/index.js#L156), this should work:

```
var mongo = require('mongoskin');
var db    = mongo.db(DBURL, { username : USERNAME, password : PASSWORD, ... });
```

Comment: Ah thanks, weird that there's nothing in the docs (as far as I can see) about this format.  I'll give it a try.